# I want to know the working process of this python program

Tags: python

here i called the sm() with arguments a,b  but i didn't give any arguments in out()

in my view i'm thinking that a error would be raised. But it 
                 works fine

```
def out():
    c=sm(a,b)  
    print(c)

a=6 
b=8

def sm(a,b):
    return a + b

out()
```

Comment: You can access variables defined outside a function in the function in Python. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding

Comment: Did you not ask this a couple of minutes ago? Please [edit] your original question instead of posting it (badly) again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code currently is, it should work fine without any error. Here the variables `a=6` and `b=8` are **global** so if you don't give any arguments to it, it will get the values of `a` & `b` from **global** frame. See step by step Frame and Objects [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20out%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20c%3Dsm%28a,b%29%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20print%28c%29%0A%0Aa%3D6%0Ab%3D8%0A%0Adef%20sm%28a,b%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%20b%0A%0Aout%28%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=4&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

```
def out():
    c=sm(a,b)  # so available here
    print(c)

a=6 # global variable
b=8 # global variable

def sm(a,b):
    return a + b 

out()
```

**Execution Context**

[image: execution context]

Answer (score 0):

Basically in this program you have two functions `out()` and `sm()`,
first function `sm()` takes two arguments `a,b` as input and return their sum as output
while other function `out()` just calling `sm()` function with inputs `a,b`
which is defined globally and store their sum in `c` variable then printing the `c` variable which gives output `8`

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. 
Initially, a function named out() is defined.
The process starts at initializing a=6 and b=8 globally.
Then you have defined sm(a,b) function, nothing happens
Then you called the function out() which you have defined earlier. So we got into the function out() which has no parameters.
Inside it, you have called function sm(a,b) which you earlier defined. So c gets the value returned by sm(6,8) which is 14. Then prints c. Thus 14 is printed.